# NestJS request returns 500 when post request is made

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am having difficulty with making post request in nestjs. Request I make return this `ERROR: An error occurred in POST /api/fraud-rules in 8ms...`

```
{
  "isError": true,
  "status": 500,
  "name": "InternalError",
  "message": "Cannot read property 'emailAddress' of undefined",
  "data": null
}
```

I am able to intercept the request and log the body, but for some reason the request just returns error and does not log in the controller.

user.controller.ts

```
  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    console.log(createUserDto);
    return await this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
  }
```

user.service.ts

```
  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise< User > {
    let data: Prisma.UserCreateInput = {};
    data = Object.assign(data, createFraudRuleDto);
    return await this.usersRepository.create(data);
  }
```

user.repository.ts

```
  async create(data: Prisma.UserCreateInput): Promise<User | null> {
    return this.prisma.user.create({ data });
  }
```

I tried to log data in the controller to see what data comes in but it does not log in my console.

I ran the application with `nest start --debug --watch`

Comment: show us where you are doing the `x.emailAddress` prop access. Looks like `x` is `undefined` somehow

Comment: Can you add your `CreateUserDto` class in your question ?

Comment: @MicaelLevi @marco you both were right. The issue was with my `CreateUserDto` and the argument in the constructor was undefined.

Comment: a `@Post()` request from the controller is not asynchronous if you are doing it like so: `@Post('/signup')
  createUser(@Body() body: CreateUserDto) {
    this.usersService.create(body.email, body.password);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the bug was in my user.dto.ts file I had

```
export class CreateUserDto implements IUser {
    constructor(user: IUser) {
        this.emailAddress = user.emailAddress;
        ....
    }
}
```

Apparently when request are made the constructor us called without the `user`. This led to the error in the question.

Refactoring from above to this

```
export class CreateUserDto implements IUser {
    constructor(user: IUser) {
        if (user) {
            this.emailAddress = user.emailAddress;
            ....
        }
     }
}
```

Fixed the issue.

Credit @MicaelLevi, @marco